# xpath : test if node is the only child other than specified ok elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to write an xsl template that checks to see if a given node is the only child node, other than certain specified elements :

in this example, <target/> will be changed to <hit/> as it is the only <target/> node, and only <ok/> nodes precede it

```
<root>
<!-- this is ok, the ok nodes are at the top, followed by only 1 target -->
<mynode>
    <ok1/>
    <ok2/>
    <target/>
</mynode>

<!-- will fail, bad element before target -->
<mynode>
    <ok1/>
    <ok2/>
    <bad/>
    <target/>
</mynode>

<!-- no match, multiple target nodes -->
<mynode>
    <ok1/>
    <ok2/>
    <target/>
    <target/>
</mynode>
</root>
```

I was using this xpath :

```
<xsl:template match="target[not(following-sibling::*)]
                       [not(preceding-sibling::target)]
                       [not(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), 'bad' or 'hello')])]
                 ">
    <hit>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </hit>
</xsl:template>
```

In that last predicate, do I have to indicate specifically any node I don't want? Can I something like

```
not(preceding-sibling::*[not(starts-with(name(), 'ok'))])
```

thanks

Comment: Is it still a match if there are ok elements _after_ the target?

Comment: @JLRishe In the OP's XPath expression it seems that `target` must be the last child node of `mynode`. Just guessing though.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Well, that's what the examples seem to indicate, but that's not consistent with the description of the problem: _"I want to write an xsl template that checks to see if a given node is the only child node, other than certain specified elements"_. I guess I'll need to provide both answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
<xsl:template match="target[count(../*) = 
                            count(../*[starts-with(name(), 'ok')]) + 1]">
    <hit>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </hit>
</xsl:template>
```

The interpretation is to match `target` if:

- The number of all child elements of its parent *is equal to*
- The number of all good child elements of its parent plus one (itself)

**Edit** If you only want to match the element if it's the *last* child of its parent (you didn't say so in your question, but your examples suggest that), you can add `and not(following-sibling::*)` to the predicate above, or here is an alternative approach:

```
<xsl:template match="target[not(following-sibling::*) and 
                            not(preceding-sibling::*[not(starts-with(name(), 'ok'))])
                           ]">
```

but you seem to have already figured that one out on your own.

**Lastly,** if what you actually want to do is allow certain specific OK elements and not match the names based on a prefix, you can use `self::` for this:

```
<xsl:template match="target[count(../*) = 
                            count(../*[self::allgood or self::great]) + 1]">

<xsl:template match="target[not(following-sibling::*) and 
                            not(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::allgood or
                                                         self::great     )]
                               )]">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[not(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), 'bad' or 'hello')])]
```

won't work as 'bad' or 'hello' is boolean or string
You also don't need to use double not()
and simply do

```
preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(),'ok')]
```

You can also create a whitelist or a blacklist and iterate over it with a contains() XPath function, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="oks" select="ok1 ok2 ok3"/>
```

and then match

```
preceding-sibling::*[contains($oks, name())]
```

Comment: Can you please explain how a complete stylesheet using your suggestion would look like? Not having the double negative does _not_ work, because then there can be preceding siblings that are not named "ok". Also, I do not understand what you mean by "is boolean or string".